# Why is this floating point addition result not correct?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, addition

I am trying to calculate the time in `buffer` in microseconds.

But I don't understand why the floating-point operation result of my code is not correct.

```
float time, sec; 
int h, m;
sscanf(16:41:48.757996, "%d:%d:%f", &h, &m, &sec);
printf("buffer %s\n",buffer);
printf("hour %d\n",h);
printf("minute %d\n",m);
printf("seconde %f\n",sec);
time=3600*h+60*m;+sec;
printf("%f\n",time);
```

When I execute this code, I get the following result:

```
buffer 16:41:48.757996
heure 16
minute 41
seconde 48.757996
60108.757812
```

But I am expecting:

```
buffer 16:41:48.757996
heure 16
minute 41
seconde 48.757996
60108.757996
```

The result of the floating-point operation is not correct.

Comment: Float arithmetic has many pitfalls which often surprise even long time programmers. Just google for it,

Comment: Read about rounding errors: http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C%282f%29FloatingPoint.html

Comment: @olaf thank you, but how can do it?  I have no ideas! Please help me!

Comment: Here's a hint: look at the name of the type: *float*ing-point. Unless you want the point to be able to "float", i.e. to change the number of digits on either side of it as a result of an operation, you don't need to be using this type. It is not, and should not be confused with, a general purpose fractional type (you can always use scaled integer operations for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) encoding, many numbers will have small changes to allow them to be stored.Also, the number of significant digits can change slightly since it is a binary representation, not a decimal one.

**Single precision (float)** gives you **23 bits** of significand, 8 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.

**Double precision (double)** gives you **52 bits** of significand, 11 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.

Following code snippet will work for you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double time, sec; // changed to double
    double h, m;
    sscanf("16:41:48.757996", "%lf:%lf:%lf", &h, &m, &sec);
    printf("hour %lf\n",h);
    printf("minute %lf\n",m);
    printf("seconde %lf\n",sec);
    time=3600*h+60*m+sec;
    printf("%lf\n",time);
}
```

Comment: One can generally add the hidden bit to the bits in the significand, giving a single-precision number 24 bits in the significand, likewise 53 bits in the significand of a double-precision number.

Answer (score 4):

I think, you have a small typo in your code. Change

```
time=3600*h+60*m;+sec;
```

to

```
time=3600*h+60*m+sec;  // remove ; from the apparent middle of the statement
                ^^
```

Otherwise, the `sec` value is becoming *essentially* useless.

That said, always check for the return value of `sscanf()` to ensure success.

---

EDIT:

As others have pointed out, the main reason behind losing the precision is due to the use of `float` type. It is nicely explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736121/why-is-this-floating-point-addition-result-not-correct/30736857#30736857) that, changing the variable type to `double` will increase the precision and you'll get a fine-grained result, as you've expected.

Comment: Th sec value is correct when I display it. But the value of the calculation isn't correct... I would like to display the time values in micro seconds, but it is not correct.

Comment: yes but I don't understand why you say to check the return value of sscanf() while the values ​​of h, m and sec are good. The problem is just about the calculation

Comment: @flat1991 well, that is just a suggestion, (that's why appears at last). More of a token of "Good Coding Habit".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @haccks you're right. my bad. I stopped following as soon as I pointed that typo. I should have noticed, that mistakes should have caused a much bigger difference in value. Will update my answer, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change `float` to `double` if want more precision

```
double time, sec;
```

and use `%lf` in `sscanf`. You will get the desired result.

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/ntdR8w)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. And for the last two lines:                              time=3600*h+60*m;+sec;
printf("%f\n",time);      it is ok like that?

Comment: Yes. Except you need to remove `;` from `time=3600*h+60*m;+sec;`.

Comment: This is not at all about precision. `float` will do just fine for his purpose. It's the typo that messes up the result.

Comment: @mastov; What? Are you serious?

Comment: @haccks: OK, there's also *some* precision loss because of `float`, but the typo has a much bigger effect.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation is good with doubles!

```
double time, sec;
sscanf(buffer, "%d:%d:%lf", &h, &m, &sec);
printf("buffer %s\n",buffer);
printf("heure %d\n",h);
printf("minute %d\n",m);
printf("seconde %f\n",sec);

P.TempsEmission=3600*h+60*m+sec;    
printf("%lf\n",P.TempsEmission);
```